# Connection to Hive using python and Kerberos

Tags: python, hive, configuration, kerberos, pyhive

I'm trying to connect to hive using Python. I installed all of the dependencies required (sasl, thrift_sasl, etc..)

Here is how I try to connect:

```
configuration = {"hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal" : "hive/_HOST@REALM_HOST", "hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab" : "/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab"}

connection = hive.Connection(configuration = configuration, host="host", port=port, auth="KERBEROS", kerberos_service_name = "hiveserver2")
```

But I get this error:

> Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "REALM_DOMAIN")

Whay I'm missing? Does someone has an example of an `pyHive` connection using `kerberos`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Kishore.
Actually in PySpark, the code looks like this :

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def connection(self):
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

    self.cursor = HiveContext(sc)

    self.cursor.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    self.cursor.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    self.cursor.setConf("hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms", "true")
    self.cursor.setConf('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')
```

and you can request using :

```
rows = self.cursor.sql("SELECT someone FROM something")
for row in rows.collect():
    print row
```

I'm actually running the code via the command :

```
spark-submit --master yarn MyProgram.py
```

I guess you could using basically run the python with pyspark installed like :

```
python MyProgram.py
```

but I didn't tried so I won't assure that it's working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in pyspark, but I am using below scala code and it is working since last one year. If you can change this code in python. Replace the value of properties based on your kerberos.

```
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "add hive.metastore.uris url");
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true")
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file", "add keytab")
System.setProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "false")
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", "replace hive.metastore.kerberos.principal value")
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true")
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
```